# How to convert very large numbers back and forth?

Tags: elixir

I work with some API of cryptocurrencies. This involvolves very large numbers - 10 ** 18

What I need for now is only convert numbers from the smallest units to the normal ones:

```
X ** 10 pow (6, 9, 12... 18) ----> X

Y ----> Y ** 10 pow (6, 9, 12... 18)
```

How to do it properly in Elixir? What's an error-proof way?

**update 1**

for those who are as stupid as @ Adam Millerchip

```
123000000000000000000 -> 123
123 -> 123000000000000000000
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples in elixir of the number formats you want to convert between.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip re-read the question carefully

Answer (score 1):

```elixir
iex(1)> div(123000000000000000000, 10 ** 18)
123
iex(2)> 123 * 10 ** 18
123000000000000000000
```

Comment: `123000000000000000000 |> to_string |> String.split_at(-18) |> elem(0) |> String.to_integer`